# how can I find who call my bash application

Tags: linux, bash

This may look a silly simple question, but I can't find the appropriate method to find the caller.

I have a tool that can be used from different applications. I want to record who is using it.

Note that when sourcing, using `source` (or the dot shortcut), the executing program is `bash` (or your designated shell). In this case, only if you source  'tool', the calling history will be preserved on `${BASH_SOURCE[*]}`, including the calling line on `${BASH_LINENO[*]}`.

I expect BASH_SOURCE give some hint (history), however, the tool is not sourced so, there is no references to caller on 'BASH_SOURCE'.

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is the tool: I'm expecting to have 'client' somewhere
echo "Source ${BASH_SOURCE[*]}"
ps -axj | grep "\s$$\s"
echo "tool: ${*}"
```

now, this is the client caller

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is the client
chmod +x ./tool            # I'm making this explicit
./tool this is a test
```

This is the result:

```
$ . ./client
Source ./tool
30389 17217 17217 30389 pts/1    17217 S+       0   0:00 /bin/bash ./tool this is a test
17217 17218 17217 30389 pts/1    17217 R+       0   0:00 ps -axj
17217 17219 17217 30389 pts/1    17217 S+       0   0:00 grep \s17217\s
30380 30389 30389 30389 pts/1    17217 Ss       0   0:01 -bash
tool: this is a test
```

Comment: This might help: [How do I get the parent process ID of a given child process?](https://askubuntu.com/q/153976/336375)

Comment: Have you tried to replace `$$` by `$PPID` in `./tool` ?

Answer (score 1):

Would adding `ps -o comm= -p $PPID` to `tool` do what you're after?

Edit:
Adding sample output

```
tink@box ~/tmp$ ./client 
Source ./tool
15576 15578 15576  9978 pts/3    15576 S+    1000   0:00 /bin/bash ./tool this is a test
tool: this is a test
client
```

Comment: Well.. the answer is 'bash' and this is not what I'm expecting. I will add that with `ps -xa -o pid,pgid,sid,ppid,comm=` the client is not even there!

Comment: @fcm  How odd ... it works for me;  see edited output (I added the suggested line to the bottom of your `tool` script.

Comment: You are right, but you are not sourcing 'client'. If you - x will do it.

Answer (score 1):

This might help with Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
GPPID=$(ps -o ppid= -p $PPID | tr -d ' ')
cat /proc/$GPPID/comm
```